# R: How do I create weights for my network based on frequency?

Tags: r, network-analysis

I have an edgelist (2 columns) and I want to create a 3rd column with weights to each node based on the number of mentions of each word of my data.

See attached my data.

For example: 'oil' 'bad' 'gas' appear multiple times and I would like to add value '1' for every time the same one appear (and delete the multiple rows).

[dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXDjH.png)

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image. None of us want to type it all in. Instead, use `dput`  to create a text version of your data and include it in your question. If you have too much data to include it all, you can just provide the beginning with `dput(head(dat, 20))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution for this case would be just to use `table`

```
#create some sample data
set.seed(1)
node1<-rep("oil drilling", 20)
node2<-sample(c("gas", "frack", "pollute", "good"),20,replace=T)

edglst<-data.frame(node1, node2)              

head(edglist,10)

          node1   node2
1  oil drilling   frack
2  oil drilling   frack
3  oil drilling pollute
4  oil drilling    good
5  oil drilling     gas
6  oil drilling    good
7  oil drilling    good
8  oil drilling pollute
9  oil drilling pollute
10 oil drilling     gas

#use table to get a dataframe with one row per combination and its frequency
as.data.frame(table(edglst))

    node1   node2 Freq
1 oil drilling   frack    5
2 oil drilling     gas    4
3 oil drilling    good    6
4 oil drilling pollute    5
```

**EDIT** : You may also need to remove some 0's if you have some possible combinations of nodes that don't occur in your data, in which case

```
x<-as.data.frame(table(edglst))
x<-x[!x$Freq==0,]
```

Comment: Nice solution +1  but if there are node1-node2 pairs that do not occur in the data,  you will get unsightly  rows with 0 weight

Comment: thanks! the count function work as the as.data.frame(table(x)), but does not include combinations with zero counts

Answer (score 2):

I do not want to type your data in so I will illustrate with some generated data.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 20, replace=TRUE)
y = sample(letters[1:6], 20, replace=TRUE)
dat = data.frame(x,y)
```

You can get the count that you want from the `count` function in the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
count(dat)
   x y freq
1  A b    1
2  A d    1
3  B b    4
4  B e    1
5  B f    2
6  D a    3
7  D b    2
8  D e    2
9  E c    1
10 F b    1
11 F d    1
12 F e    1
```

Comment: awesome, the count function gives me what I need, but I still can't turn the "freq" column from it in a 3rd column in my original dataset according to each word.

Comment: That's what I've been trying:

`require( "plyr")
count2<-count(dat$to)

dat$weight[dat$to == count2$x] <- count2$freq`

I get the error:

`Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(dat$to, count2$x) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In dat$weight[dat$to == count2$x] <- count2$freq :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`


So I guess the problem is that I have 554 unique words, but 3336 rows (observations).